# 0 visitors/day as reported on 17 Dec 01:45 hours IST / 16 Dec 20:15 GMT?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

This is obviously not true:

[image]

Has this happened before?

Comment: The joke (and the honesty) is that most small problems you see on this site are due to some sort of chaching.  Meaning it might fix itself over time.

Answer (score 2):

I've never noticed that before, and when I view it (at 15.25Eastern / 20.25 GMT) I see over 14,000 visitors a day.

Do you still see 0?

Comment: Nope. Not after that!